# Is it a good practice to run the API in the Backend even after API has returned a Response?

Tags: api, amazon-s3, sails.js, image-manipulation, sequelize.js

My Requirement is to resize an Image when the image is put on the s3 bucket. I implemented this requirement using `AWS Lambda`. But `AWS Lambda` requires two `S3 Buckets` for this implementation (`SourceBucket` and `DestinationBucket`).

I found out that the same can be implemented at an `API` level using `sails js`,`Sequelize` ORM and `npm` modules where I can return the `response` of the `API` first and then let the `API` do the image resizing operation and saving it on `s3 bucket` operation in the backend after the `API` has returned the response.

I am unable to understand whether or not to run the image resizing operation after giving the API response is a good practice or not. Can somebody help me on this ?

Comment: If you sure that resizing can be done asynchronously and don't depends on response then yes, you can do it.